# Как каждый раз не подгружать изображение?

Tags: html, css, кэширование

Такой вопрос, на странице имеется около 200 позиционированных изображений, естественно при любом обновлении страницы - они грузятся вновь и "мигают".
Можно ли как-то кэшировать? Чтобы они заново не подгружались.

Answer (score 1):

Через .htaccess. Создаёшь в корне сайта файл с названием .htaccess если его нет и заполняешь его следующим содержимым.

```
# кеш браузера
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On

#по умолчанию кеш в 5 секунд
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"

# Включаем кэширование изображений и флэш на месяц
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 4 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 43829 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"

# Включаем кэширование css, javascript и текстовых файлов на одну неделю
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"

# Включаем кэширование html и htm файлов на один день
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"

# Включаем кэширование xml файлов на десять минут
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"

# Нестандартные шрифты сайта
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Andrey, благодарю! Но, есть некоторые изображение которые обновляются чуть ли не каждые пол минуты, возможно ли с них снять кэширование?

Answer (score 1):

> Такой вопрос, на странице имеется около 200 позиционированных изображений, естественно при любом обновлении страницы - они грузятся вновь и "мигают".
>
> Можно ли как-то кэшировать?

Есть такое понятие `Lazy Loading (LZ)`, вы подгружаете не всё сразу, а по мере необходимости. Такое можно проделывать и с другими елементами сайта не только с изображениями.

Напримеры событий для подгрузки:

1. Юзер скролит страницу и по мере скролла подгружаются следующие фотки.
2. Любые другие события, которые можете придумать.

Вот что можно поискать:

- Lazy Load (jQuery)
- Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery
- BJ Lazy Load
- bLazy.js

---

Есть еще пару моментов, такие как `SEO` и `Mobile`.

1. `SEO` Гуглаботы не видят элементы "отложенной загрузки", хотя LZ довольно частый прием для разгрузки сайта, и уменьшения расходов на трафик в целом.
2. Экономия мобильного тарфика и быстрота подгрузки всего сайта, никто не любит ждать.

---

Это не отменяет кэширование у себя на сайте (`Apache/Nginx/.htaccess`) или с испоьзованием `CDN`.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Дело в том, что как раз все эти изображения "влазят" в один экран, там как бы каталог, поэтому нужно именно кэшировать. Много ищу уже, каким образом это сделать, пока что к сожалению бесполезно. Думал тут помогут.

Comment: @Holter приветствую, а вы каталог когда в магазине берете, там тоже все изображения на одной странице или всё-таки листать приходиться? =)